# C++ What's the difference between <Type> and <Type *>

Tags: c++, types, casting, type-conversion

Is there a difference between using `<Type>` and `<Type *>` ?

When I try do this

```
Double_node<Type> *list_head;
list_head = new Double_node <Type>(Type(), nullptr, nullptr);
```

I get no errors, but when I do

```
 Double_sentinel_list<Type *> list;
list = new Double_sentinel_list<Type>();
```

I get

Error   4   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Double_sentinel_list *'

Comment: Paraphrased: Is there a difference between pointer and pointee?

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
Double_node<Type> *list_head;
```

is declaration of pointer to an object Double_node.
Therefore you can assign an object created on a heap using new.

Code:

```
Double_sentinel_list<Type *> list;
```

is declaration of an object on stack of type Double_sentinel_list, where this next type is some kind of list of pointers to Type.
Therefore you cannot assign an object created on heap.

You need to learn the basic syntax of c++ and the difference between stack, heap and what are pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the types are not equal.

When you call the constructor with new it's returning a

```
 Double_sentinel_list<Type>*
```

read: pointer to Double_sentinel_list with template type Type. The variable you're trying to assign it to is a

```
 Double_sentinel_list<Type*>
```

read: Double_sentinel_list with template type pointer to Type.